# How to generate unique names for variables?

Tags: c#

I have my own class, `Question`. I have code which must be able to create new objects from this class at will, like this:

```
Question qst1 = new Question(parameters)
```

But I have no idea how many of them I should create. So, how do I generate unique names for the new questions and generate a question with that name?

This is what I tried, building a string with the question number in `temp` and trying to declare a variable named `Question0`, `Question1`, and so on, using `Question temp`:

```
string temp = "Question" + currentNumber.ToString();
currentNumber++;
Question temp = new Question("parameter1","parameter2");
```

But that doesn't compile. Is there a way to use the string in `temp` as a variable?

Comment: Is there a database you are using to store this data or are you relying on the file system or is this simply in memory?

Comment: @BillBerry Are you seriously confusing him with databases? The poor guy. Seems like he just has a list of objects, without the list.

Comment: I think he's asking for the compile-time variable name to be computed from run-time computations, which of course is impossible.  Should use an array or List<Question> instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know how many elements there are going to be, you could use a `List<T>`:

```
var questions = new List<Question>();

var question = new Question(parameters);
questions.Add(question);

question = new Question(parameters2);
questions.Add(question);
```

Then you can access questions in the list, by directly accessing them or looping over them:

```
var questionTouse = questions[0];

// or

foreach (var q in questions)
{
    // do something with q
}
```

An alternative, if you want to be able to look up questions by their string key that *you* assign, you could use a `Dictionary<string, Question>()`:

```
var questions = new Dictionary<string, Question>();

var question = new Question(parameters);
questions["Question1"] = question;

question = new Question(parameters2);
questions["Question2"] = question;
```

Then to get items out of the dictionary, you refer to them by the key you added them with, or again, loop over them:

```
var questionTouse = questions["Question1"];

// or

foreach (var q in questions)
{
    // do something with q
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array

```
var questions = new Question[numquestion];
for (int i = 0 to numquestion)
{
   questions[i] = new Question(...);
}
```

now you can refer to questions[n]

Comment: I like the VB# code. A combination of some VB.Net and C#.